# Exported STL looks distorted

Tags: modeling, export, stl

### Blender 2.77a

### Problem

When I export this blend, external software shows it as heavily deformed. Blender shows it fine and so does the Windows Object Viewer.

[image: Blender Edit Mode]

Shapeways and Tinkercad however shows the following:

[image: Tinkercad]

I've tried to export stl, obj and other formats (ultimately I'll need stl) and they all come out the same. I have tried to convert quads to tris, but that did not produce a different result.

Object is manifold, has no loose geometry, no doubles and no pending modifiers.

Anyone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: is there possibly a decimate modifier somewhere on your modifier stack? If so, uncheck its render visibility before export.

Comment: Either your exported mesh is meshed differently than in your first screenshot or Shapeways/Tinkercad are remeshing .stl meshes at import time. I think the later is very likely. Could you open your .stl in a program like Meshlab and see if the tesselation is the same (or alternatively share it here) ? It is clear in your second screenshot that the .stl is remeshed in a weird way.

Comment: Is the first screen shot the imported stl in blender, or the original mesh?

Comment: @aliasguru No modifiers on the stack.

Comment: @nantille Meshlabs shows the mesh correctly. Remeshing is possible, however Tinkercad and Shapeways seem to render the object similarly.

Comment: @David the first screenshot is the original, completely modeled within blender.

Comment: Are the [transforms for the object applied](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html#apply-object-transformations) ? Also there are Ngons in your mesh which might be converted somehow to tris incorrectly, try exporting a simpler object and testing that.

Comment: @MrZak All transforms have been applied and quads/ngons converted to tris. No dice... I simply don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this has something to do with the size of your object - perhaps the images we are looking at are at least 400% bigger than what you hope to print? If that is the case the image might look distorted but is correct for the resolution that it is actually printing.

Comment: It imports really small. I tried exporting it with a scale of 10, but unfortunately that doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Blender has a rather confusing issue with scale. I work in metric and expect if my model is 10cm high it should be that when exported, but most 3D programs would read it as 1mm high. In Blender's defense there are no standard units for .STL but there could be, and in my opinion should be - considering most 3D programs seem to handle the unit conversion. Try save up your model 100 times bigger and the size is probably accurate. Check the dimension in the quote too - you will probably also notice the price will go up a bit :)

Comment: BAM! Exported it with a scale of 100 and that fixed the issue. Now it's way too big, but I can fix that easily now that it imports the mesh well. Still a few artifacts, but it could be related. Going to mark this issue as resolved.